# AJAX PHP Call to localhost database returning error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database

I'm making a web-application library with a button that, when clicked, calls a checkout() function. This function uses jQuery to post data to a PHP script. this PHP then connects to a database on localhost (for now) and sends a query.

When executed inside MySQL Workbench, the query shown in the PHP below works perfectly. My problem arises when I try to execute it from the web page. It connects just fine with the db user and password, but the query itself fails.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-4 btn btn-default button" onclick="checkout();">
    Checkout
</div>
```

**The JS**

```
function checkout() {
    let result=$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/checkout.php",
        dataType: "text",
        //@TODO: add scanner functionality to populate isbn,
        //  add functionality to populate user
        data:
        {
            isbn: 1,
            user: 1
        },
        success: function(result) {
            //change #button-text to house result (for now)
            // @TODO: delete errorcheck when done
            $('#button-text').html(result);
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status + ' ||| ' + error);
        }
    });
}
```

**The PHP**

```
    $dbconn = connectToDB($serverName, $dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
    // set is_available to false, update checkout and due
    // date, update current owner of book, set due_date to
    // current date + 14 days
    $query = "UPDATE books
                    SET is_available = false,
                        checkout_date = CURDATE(),
                        due_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),
                        INTERVAL 14 DAY)
                    WHERE isbn = $isbn;

                    INSERT INTO currently_checked_out_books
                    (user_id, book_isbn, due_date)
                    VALUES (
                        $user,
                        $isbn,
                        DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
                    );";
    // $query = "show tables;"; // returns what you'd expect
    $result = $dbconn->query($query);
```

**What I've Tried:**

I double and triple checked my query and my database permissions - the db user I have setup has DB Manager privileges, meaning it should be able to do whatever it wants with the database. As previously stated, I also tested my query directly in MySQL Workbench, and it worked properly. The only thing I can think of is that my db user isn't setup properly, but again, if anything it has *too much* freedom.

Additional information and clarification provided upon request - if I missed any important needed info, please let me know.

Comment: you're attempting to do a multi query but not using the right function for it.

Comment: What is the error message you get back? I cannot see where you assign $user,$isbn from $_POST['user'] and $_POST['isbn']. Plus the multi query as already noted by FunkFortyNiner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have more than one statement in `$query` but you're using `$dbconn->query($query)` which doesn't support multiple statements as also reported in [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php):

> Multiple statements or multi queries must be executed with
>   mysqli_multi_query(). The individual statements of the statement
>   string are separated by semicolon. Then, all result sets returned by
>   the executed statements must be fetched.

Therefore you need to split your statements or leave `$query` as it is and use `$result = $dbconn->multi_query($query);`.